# Simple JDT example of code generation

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I'm trying to write an Eclipse plugin. It will have dependencies on the RCP for basic stuff and JDT for Java code generation. It consists of a Wizard / WizardPage which asks for a package and a few class names. When the user hits "Finish", I want the wizard to create classes corresponding to the entered values into the current Java project.

I have the basic UI working. What I cannot figure out is how to generate the corresponding class code. Eclipse documentation is a bit hard to follow. From what I can glean I need to first obtain an IJavaProject from the workspace, from that an IPackageFragment and from that I can call createCompilationUnit() to make a class.

What I can't do is find any working examples. I assume that somehow I can walk from the workspace root to where I need to be and create the unit.

Can anyone offer some pointers to simple working code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to extend NewElementWizardPage and provide the functionality. See [this documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_wizards.htm) for more details

Answer (score 0):

> I assume that somehow I can walk from the workspace root to where I need to be and create the unit.

Yes.  Take a look at IProject, IFolder, and IFile in the org.eclipse.core.resources package.

> Can anyone offer some pointers to simple working code?

Eclipse itself creates a new Java class with a limited skeleton when you ask it to, using the New Java Class Wizard.  That source code would be helpful to you for what you want to do.  I couldn't find it with a cursory search of Eclipse and the Eclipse help.  I'm guessing it's somewhere in an org.eclipse.pde package.

You might also look at Creation Wizards, which is the extension point org.eclipse.ui.newWizards.